# Using a variable range to update the data labels in a graph

Tags: charts, label, excel-2016

I will be using an InputBox to select a range to use as data labels.
I can not get the code to accept the variable.
The code shown works but if I move the 'comment' on the last line to the penultimate line then the data labels are not updated.
I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks in advance.

Sub Data_Label_Range()

```
Dim rng As Range

' an Inputbox is used to select the range. Code removed for simpilicty
Set rng = Range("$T$3:$T$34")

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph_Avg_Monthly").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowValue = True
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "='Avg Monthly score'!$T$3:$T$34", 0
' ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=rng", 0
```

End Sub

Comment: I have found an identical problem and @FlexYourData responded but the poster never replied. How can I contact FlexYourData and request help. I have made two changes and used  rng.AddressLocal without quotes and set showValue to FALSE, but this still does not update the data labels. No error messages are given'

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and this is the full macro.

Sub Set_Graph_Data_Labels()

Dim rng As Range

```
Range("T3").Select
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Title:="Data Label Selection", _
Prompt:="Select range for Data Labels", _
Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If rng.column = 20 Then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph_Avg_Monthly").Activate
    With ActiveChart
    .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
        InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, _
        rng.AddressLocal(External:=True), 0
End With
Else
    MsgBox "You did not select the correct column of data"
End If
Range("D75").Select
```

End Sub

The relevant code is
InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange,rng.AddressLocal(External:=True), 0

Without (External:=True) the macro runs but does not update the data labels.
Not sure of the difference between rng.AddressLocal and rng.Address  They both seem to work.